# Change date format

Tags: date, format

I use a plugin that shows me list of posts and I want to change format of date.
This is show me date like this:

**24 january 2015 12:20:11**
and this is the code of above output:

```
<?php echo $post->getCreatedTime(); ?>
```

But I want to show date like this:

**24 january 2015**

I use this code but this is show time in wrong month and date, for example instead of **24 january 2015** it shows me: **Oct 12, 2015** !!!

```
<?php $_ct= new Zend_Date($post->getCreatedTime()); echo $_ct->toString('MMM dd, yyyy'); ?>
```

I don't have any idea why this is happen!!!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about locale! As all other examples can cause issues for people from different time zones.

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
```

inside `date()` you can put any date and call method `->toString()` with some param.

Pattern examples you can find in `Varien_Date`

```
const DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
const DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd';

const DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT       = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
const DATE_PHP_FORMAT           = 'Y-m-d';
```

or use any you like.

For example for current time full call will look like this:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime() function. See updated code below.

```
$_ct= new Zend_Date(strtotime($post->getCreatedTime()));
echo $_ct->toString('MMM dd, yyyy');    // will output Jan 24, 2015
```

Comment: When I use your code my page messed up and all data remove from page.

Comment: just wrap the parameter in Zend_Date function with strtotime()

Comment: How can I do it? I am new in magento, please explain me more, thanks.

Comment: just change this line and check `$_ct= new Zend_Date(strtotime($post->getCreatedTime()));`

Comment: When I just use `<?php $_ct= new Zend_Date(strtotime($post->getCreatedTime())); ?>` all data of my page will remove again!!!

Comment: Can you check the value of `$post->getCreatedTime()` . I think it is null

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: just put this line `echo $post->getCreatedTime()`

Comment: Oh , yes, I write this  output in my question, it show me : 24 january 2015 12:20:11

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I have use today this format which is working fine.

```
$createdtime = new Zend_Date(strtotime($post->getCreatedTime()));
echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('M d, Y', $createdtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$date = $post->getCreatedTime();
$dateToShow = date('j F Y',strtotime($date));
echo $dateToShow;
```

About the exact format just use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Your code show me this date: 1 January 1970 instead of 24 january 2015!!!

Comment: I m using the same.Either you did something wrong with the copy paste or the $date is null

Comment: No, I copy your code properly and $date isn't null because I created post that the date of each post show properly in admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to set your local time zone. so it's get your server time and print as you wish.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
```

set your time zone. check if any problem tell me.

Happy Codding . :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$anyDate = '24 january 2015 12:20:11';
echo $currentDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('d F Y', $anyDate);
```